# The class `OidcTenantConfig` can't be resolved, why?

Tags: java, openid-connect, quarkus

## **Question:**

The class `OidcTenantConfig` can't be resolved, why? That's lead to the question: Where can I find the javadoc for `io.quarkus.oicd` ?

I can't find the reason for my problem and I was wondering, why can't I find the javadoc in the [Quarkus javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.quarkus) for `io.quarkus.oicd`?

## **Situation/Problem:**

> The class `OidcTenantConfig` can't be resolved.

I going to customize what is given in the [Quarkus example](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-multitenancy)

This is the error I got during the build:

```sh
/CustomTenantConfigResolver.java:[8,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class OidcTenantConfig
[ERROR]   location: package io.quarkus.oidc.runtime
```

### **Implementation details:**

For a better understanding.

- Maven/Import/Code:

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-oidc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-oidc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

```java
// Tenant
import io.quarkus.oidc.TenantConfigResolver;

// The following import causes the error:
import io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcTenantConfig;

import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
```

```java
public OidcTenantConfig resolve(RoutingContext context) {
        System.out.println("-->log: com.ibm.web-api.CustomTenantResolver.resolve : " + context.request().path());

        String path = context.request().path();
        String[] parts = path.split("/");

        if (parts.length == 0) {
            // resolve to default tenant configuration
            return null;
        }

        if ("articles".equals(parts[1])) {
            OidcTenantConfig config = new OidcTenantConfig();

            config.setTenantId("tenantB");
            config.setAuthServerUrl("http://localhost:8282/auth/realms/tenantB");
            config.setClientId("backend-service");
            OidcTenantConfig.Credentials credentials = new OidcTenantConfig.Credentials();
```

Comment: Can you please mark the line in the class the error is referring to

Comment: @8bit The import is the problem, as it seems: 
```// The following import causes the error:
import io.quarkus.oidc.runtime.OidcTenantConfig;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that is a bug in the documentation the class that you are looking for is in the parent package

`import io.quarkus.oidc.OidcTenantConfig`

Comment: Good catch, I created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/18455 to fix it.